# AngularJS $exceptionHandler custom callback in a controller

Tags: javascript, angularjs, exception

I am trying to catch exceptions in my AngularJS app. Currently, I override $exceptionHandler to catch exceptions and send it to the server for logging:

```
angular.module('jsDebug', []).factory('$exceptionHandler', function () {
  return function errorCatcherHandler(exception, cause) {
    StackTrace.fromError(exception).then(function(stackframes) {
      var stringifiedStack = stackframes.map(function(sf) {
        return sf.toString();
      }).join('\n');

      // sendToServer does an Ajax call for sending the exception details to the server.
      sendToServer(exception.toString() + "\nlocation=" + window.location.href + '\ncause=' + cause + '\n' + stringifiedStack, 'warning');
      console.error(exception);
    }).catch(function(err) {
      console.error(err);
    });
  };
});
```

This is good for logging purposes. However, I also want to have custom callbacks for this on my controllers, so I could handle the error depending on the controller which threw it. I want to have something like the following code on a controller that is executed whenever the exception handler catches an error:

```
exceptionHandlerCallback: function () {
    // insert code for handling errors here
}
```

Is there a way I could do this?

Comment: You could always use `$rootScope.$emit('error', error);`